# How can I style DOM after invalid input?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input, styling

I need a help in a task. I have to change color of text, border of form and append new paragraph after typed email is invalid. I wrote a code like that in JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("#mail").is(':invalid')) {
        $("#mail_label").css('color', 'red');
        $("#mail").css('border', '1px solid red');
        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var node = document.createTextNode("Invalid email address");
        para.appendChild(node);

        var element = document.getElementById("new_paragraph");
        element.appendChild(para);
        para.setAttribute('id', 'new_text');
        $("#new_text").css({'color': 'red', 'text-align': 'right', 'margin-right': '5%', 'font-size': '12px'});
    };
});
```

It is styling my DOM as I wish but from the start because my placeholder is "Enter your email address". I want it to style after invalid input. How can I make it happen?

If I change placeholder to for example xy@xy.com my site have normal styling. But when I puts in invalid mail the code don't run.

Can you please help me? It is very important for me cause this is my internship recruitment task.

Comment: you should add an `else` block for when it's valid, and also handle when the `#mail` value is empty. Consider creating something on codepen or another site to save time.

Comment: You should check if it's valid when the user enters something in the field, not on DOM ready (just once).

Comment: It's because you execute your code on pageload and since your input will be empty it will be invalid. It would be better if you executed the logic when the mail input changes.

Answer (score 0):

You better use class and css to style your document.

Here's a code that uses **'classList'** and **'cloneNode'** for a bit of optimisation.

```js
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("Invalid email address");
para.appendChild(node);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var new_paragraph = document.getElementById("new_paragraph");

  document.getElementById("mail").addEventListener("input", mail_changed);
});

function mail_changed() {
  if (!this.checkValidity()) {
    this.parentElement.classList.add("error");
    new_paragraph.appendChild(para.cloneNode(true));
  } else {
    this.parentElement.classList.remove("error");
    new_paragraph.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
form p.error input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

form p.error label {
  color: red;
}

#new_paragraph p {
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="mail" id="mail_label">Mail: </label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Enter your mail">
  </p>
</form>
<div id="new_paragraph"></div>
```

Comment: It is better than my code for sure thank you for that answer. Unfortunately it doesn't execute only on pressing "Enter" but after every key.